# Change custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using two different kinds of `UITableViewCell`s in my app. Ideally, I'd like to use them like this:

```
if (self.data.count > 0) {
    static NSString * reuseIdentifier = @"programmaticCell";
    articleCell * cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[articleCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    }

    return cell;
} else {
    static NSString * reuseIdentifier = @"programmaticCell";
    emptyCell * cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[emptyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    }

    cell.header.text = @"No data";
    [cell.button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return cell;
}
```

However, when I use the code above, it crashes. First 1 `emptyCell` will be displayed, while the data is being downloaded from the server. After it loads the `UITableView` is refreshed and the app crashes, because it's trying to use the `emptyCell` again. How can I solve this?

Comment: Provide details about the crashes.

Comment: I **highly** doubt you can use the same reusable identifier for two different kinds of UITableViewCell... You have so use a different for the two cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the same reuseIdentifier, use different ones. Another thing to check is that you've registered the custom cells with their respective identifiers with the table view.

Also if you register the cell subclasses, you don't have to check for them being nil, you are guaranteed to get instances.